# Image Segmentation UI

Tags: python, user-interface, ocr, image-segmentation

I'm doing an OCR, I already tried everything in console and it's fine. Now I am doing the visual part, in that I am a newbie and I do not have much experience, so any help is welcome, I am working with python and I have doubts on how to do the image segmentation part. I am supposed to show an image with the predicted segmentation,like this.
[image: Automatic Segmentation]
But if the user wants to modify it, he should be able to do so: Add a new box or delete and edit one already created. Like this
[image: Manual Segmentation]

But I don't have the slightest idea how to start with the UI, any recommendations? Please

Answer (score 1):

I use [annotorious](https://github.com/recogito/annotorious) and it was perfect for what I needed

Answer (score 1):

FWIW there's also a Jupyter widget built around Annotorious, in case you want (or need) to stick with Python:

https://github.com/fcollonval/ipannotoryous